# Character HH:MM to Time HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, time

I have a dataset where the time was recorded as HH:MM and is classified as a character. I want to be able to do simple calculations like duration (i.e EndTime-StartTime), and to be able to classify the time of day that the shift happened.

I have found the Chron function that stores the times as fractions of a day, and I believe that would help me do the classifications and the simple calculations, however because my data is HH:MM rather than HH:MM:SS I am running into issues.

Is there a way for me to add :00 to the end of all of my entries **OR** a way to change the class of my variable to be able to do these calculations?

Comment: `add :00 to the end` --> `paste0(myvar, ":00")`. To change the class, see TarJae's answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Many thanks to @Rui Barradas:

to avoid using paste we could simple : `lubridate::hm(your_string)`!

**First answer:**

One possible approach is to use `lubrdiate`s `hms` function in combination with `paste`:

```
your_string <- "02:04"

library(lubridate) 

hms(paste(your_string, "00"))

[1] "2H 4M 0S"
```

Comment: There's _got_ to be a dupe for this ...

Comment: There's a function `lubridate::hm(your_string)`.